# UIToolbar not showing but it's below the self.view

Tags: ios, uitoolbar

I make a toolbar in my view but I can not see it.
I use Reveal.app to check out the structure of the view 
I find out the toolbar exists and it's 
below the view so I can not see it. How can I fix this?
Of course I use

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.hidden = NO;
```

And these my screenshot:

[image]

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Subtract 44 from the toolbar origin's y-coordinate. You'll find that's equal to `self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame.size.height`.

Comment: @Kevin Thank you for you reply. And I use "    
    
    [self.navigationController.toolbar setBackgroundImage:[self scaleImage:[UIImage imageOfImageName:@"toolbar_bg"] toScale:0.5f] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];" to init the toolbar. I don't know how to subtract 44.

Comment: `bringSubviewtoFront`

Answer (score 1):

The `Navigation Bar` you have at the top pushes all of the content 44 points down.
In you storyboard or `.xib` file, you should select the view for this controller and set the **top bar** property to *Navigation Bar*. This way you will be able to work in interface builder and your content will be positioned properly.

Good luck!

### Edit

Select the your `ViewController` in `Interface Builder`:

[image: Select the your ViewController in Interface Builder:]

In the `Inspector` pane in Xcode change the `Top Bar` value

[image]

Comment: I select this controller and find the view, but where can I find the "TOP BAR"property to change? Thank you.

Comment: No,it does not work.I use "CGRect temp = self.navigationController.toolbar.frame;
    temp.origin.y = temp.origin.y - 44;
    self.navigationController.toolbar.frame = temp;" to resize the toolbar.Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Open your view's `.xib` file and select your main view of this viewController. And then choose the Attribute Inspector on the right. And in Simulated Metrics, there has an item named Top Bar. Set your top bar into Navigation Bar instead of none. I thank that will help you.